# Refreshing div inside HTML without any PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, c++, esp32

Good afternoon !

The idea behind my project is to send made-by-hand logs to a webpage so that I don't have to rely solely on the Serial Monitor.

I am sending Strings from ESP32 to a webpage that is hosted by the same ESP32.
To do that I am using ESPAsyncWebServer library that let's me use `placeholders` inside the HTML. The ESP then uses:

`String processor(const String& var)`

and

`server.on("/logs", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest* request){
       request->send(SPIFFS, "/events.html", "text/html", false, processor);
    });`

to replace the placeholder it founds with whatever piece of data I want.

I am using a circular buffer so that I don't end up using all the memory.

I googled how should I refresh a div inside a html and everywhere I looked there was a `.load('file.php')`. I don't have any .php files for my project.

#### The question is what do I load instead of that php file ?

Loading the same .html page did not work.

### events.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "master.css">   
    <title>Events Log</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#big-box').load('events.html');
refresh();
});

function refresh()
{
    setTimeout( function() {
      $('#big-box').fadeOut('slow').load('events.html').fadeIn('slow');
      refresh();
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="big-box">
        <div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_1%</div>
        <div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_2%</div>
        <div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_3%</div>
        <div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_4%</div>
        <div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_5%</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

void logOutput(String string);


//---------- Circular Buffer
template <class T>
class circular_buffer {
public:
    explicit circular_buffer(size_t size) :
        buf_(std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[size])),
        max_size_(size)
    {

    }

    void put(T item){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

        buf_[head_] = item;

        if(full_){
            tail_ = (tail_ + 1) % max_size_;
        }
        head_ = (head_ + 1) % max_size_;
        full_ = head_ == tail_;
    }

    T get() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

        if(empty()) {
            return T();
        }
        //Read data and advance the tail (we now have a free space)
        auto val = buf_[tail_];
        full_ = false;
        tail_ = (tail_ + 1) % max_size_;

        return val;
    }

    T get2() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if(empty()) {
            return T();
        }
        auto val = buf_[tail_];
        return val;
    }

    void reset() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        head_ = tail_;
        full_ = false;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        //if head and tail are equal, we are empty
        return (!full_ && (head_ == tail_));
    }

    bool full() const   {
        //If tail is ahead the head by 1, we are full
        return full_;
    }

    size_t capacity() const {
        return max_size_;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        size_t size = max_size_;

        if(!full_)  {
            if(head_ >= tail_)  {
                size = head_ - tail_;
            } else {
                size = max_size_ + head_ - tail_;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> buf_;
    size_t head_ = 0;
    size_t tail_ = 0;
    const size_t max_size_;
    bool full_ = 0;
}; //---------- Circular Buffer

circular_buffer<String> circle(20);

void logOutput(String string) {
    delay(2000);
    circle.put(string);
    Serial.println(string); 
}

AsyncWebServer server(80);

const char* ssid = "metrici.ro";
const char* password = "cocoscocos";

String processor(const String& var) { 
           if(var == "PLACEHOLDER_1"){
        return circle.get();
    } else if(var == "PLACEHOLDER_2") {
        return circle.get();
    } else if(var == "PLACEHOLDER_3") {
        return circle.get();
    } else if(var == "PLACEHOLDER_4") {
        return circle.get();
    } else if(var == "PLACEHOLDER_5") {
        return circle.get();
    }
    return String();
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(2000);

    if(!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
        logOutput("ERROR ! SPIFFS file system was not mounted. Reformatting !");
    }

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    delay(1000);
    int k = 0;
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && k<20) {
        delay(1000);
        k++;
        logOutput("Connecting to WiFi");
    }
    if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        logOutput((String)"Connected to: " + ssid + " with IP: " + WiFi.localIP().toString());
    } else {
        logOutput("Couldn't connect to WiFi ! Restarting in 5 seconds");
        delay(5000);
        ESP.restart();
    }

    server.on("/logs", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest* request){
        request->send(SPIFFS, "/events.html", "text/html", false, processor);
    });
    server.on("/master.css", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send(SPIFFS, "/master.css", "text/css");
    }); 
    server.on("/back-image.jpg", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send(SPIFFS, "/back-image.jpg", "image/jpeg");
    });
    server.on("/logo.png", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send(SPIFFS, "/logo.png", "image/png");
    });

    server.begin();
    delay(5000);

    logOutput("After server.begin()");
    for(int i = 1; i<=10;i++){
        logOutput((String)"Linia " + i);
    }
}

void loop() {
    logOutput("Beginning the loop()");
    logOutput("\n");
    delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: I stand corrected @freedomn-m. `.load` indeed is a valid jQuery API. And it does exactly what the @bleah1 expects. Sorry, about the confusion.

Comment: @elem4th no worries - it's not quite used correctly as the `.fadeIn` will occur before the `.load` - but that shouldn't stop things "working" - will just look bad

Comment: Yeah, the real issue is that jQuery isn't loaded at all. The ESP code isn't configured to serve that. Same goes for the `event.html`. Will update that in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR The ESP server doesn't serve the `/jquery-1.9.0.min.js` and `/events.html` files that the original HTML references. Read on for details.

When `$('#big-box').load('events.html')` code executes, the browser makes a HTTP GET call in background to your ESP server, at path `/event.html`. The requests on that path doesn't seem to be handled on ESP side. To handle requests on that path, you'd need something like this:

```
server.on('/event.html`, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/events-log.html", "text/html", false, processor);
})`.
```

Additionally, you'd need to create `events-log.html` file with following content (basically everything that `big-box` div contained):

```
<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_1%</div>
<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_2%</div>
<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_3%</div>
<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_4%</div>
<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_5%</div>
```

Also note, that the `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` file that you included in your HTML file (using script tag) wouldn't be loaded for same reason. The browser will try to send a HTTP GET request to `/jquery-1.9.0.min.js`, and since request on that path isn't handled, browser will get 404 error.

If the computer on which you are accessing this page has internet access, then you can load jQuery from CDN by changing your script tag to following snippet. If the machine doesn't have internet access then you'd need to download the jQuery file, save it to SPIFFS, and serve it in same manner as the other files.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great explanation ! It worked perfectly ! Thank you so much!
I've made the source into a .js file and uploaded it on the ESP and then made a path for it usind server.on();
The only question I have left is if it's ok to use html tags around the divs of the placeholders inside `/events-log.html`  Currently it's working.
`<!DOCTYPE html>`
`<html>`
`<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_1%</div>`
`<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_2%</div>`
`<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_3%</div>`
`<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_4%</div>`
`<div class="textbox">%PLACEHOLDER_5%</div>`
`</html>`

Comment: The html tags won't be necessary. Everything that you put in `event-log.html` will get injected inside the big-box div. Now, a html tag inside div tag isn't syntactically correct, but the browsers will simply ignore the tag, so you can leave them if you want.